# auth.authResponseChange event callback fires when FB.getLoginStatus() is called?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement the FB JS SDK on my website, both for logging in and also for sharing/liking content.

Here is my code:

```
// called by FB SDK once loaded (all.js)
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '913550365396947',
        cookie : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.5',
        status: false // don't check login status
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        console.log('FB.getLoginStatus callback response', response);
    });

    // auth.authResponseChange event is fired for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        console.log('auth.authResponseChange callback response: ', response);

        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            if (!shopWise.loggedIn) { // if the user isn't logged in to PW, but they are logged in to facebook
                console.warn('Logged in with facebook, but not logged in to shopwise. Reloading the page..');
                location.reload();
            }
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        } else {
        }
    });
};
```

The problem I'm having is that the `auth.authResponseChange` callback is being executed on every page load, while (if my understanding is correct) it should only be executed when the user's login state actually changes (such as logging in, or logging out).

Because the event is called on every page load, my page refresh code is executed on every page load, which means the page is in an endless refresh loop.

What's strange is that if I remove the `FB.getLoginStatus()` call, the `auth.authResponseChange` callback is not fired.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is calling `FB.getLoginStatus()` causing the `auth.authResponseChange` callback to be fired?

Comment: auth.authResponseChange

This event is fired for any auth related change as they all affect the session: login, logout, session refresh. Sessions are refreshed over time as long as the user is active with your app.

Comment: @SalmanAslam When does the session refresh? Why is the event callback only triggered when I call `getLoginStatus`, but not otherwise?

Comment: When you are logged in and you logout using other browser tab is event is fired or not??

Comment: @SalmanAslam What I'm saying is that it's being called on EVERY page load. I'm already logged in through facebook, so the event to my knowledge should not be firing unless there is a state change (which there isn't)

Comment: For sure I will check for this when i will open my laptop. but if you are only using this for liking/sharing you can check for login status before doing any action. This will make your app faster too as getLoginStatus first time checks from server then after that from local cache.

Comment: @SalmanAslam I clearly said I was using the SDK for authentication as well.

Comment: I am doing this as well in my website. And its working fine. i will check your code as well. I will hopfully be able to answer when i test your code myself.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the SDK with `status: true` instead? I suspect that initializing it with `false` might be the root of the problem here … That makes it go, “I don’t know (and don’t care) what the users current login status is” initially – and then calling `FB.getLoginStatus` _does_ actually change that, so the event firing is justified …

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I originally had it set to `true`.